# calculate time complexity from loops and conditional statement

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I calculate with the time complexity for each loop `O(n)`.
From each line of the code the time complexity is:

```
= 1 + n *((n * (1 + n * 1)) + (n * 1)))
= 1 + n * (n * (n + 1) + n)
= 1 + n * (n^2 + n + n)
= 1 + n^3 + n^2 + n^2
= 1 + n^3 + 2 * n^2`
```

So the it is `O(n^3)`.

Are my calculations correct?

**code:**

```
int result = 0 ;             //1
for (int i = 0 ; i <N ; i++){  //n 
    for (int j = 0 ; j <N ; j++){ //n

        for (int k = 0 ; k <N ; k++){ //n 

            int x = 0 ; //1
            while (x < n ){ //n 
            result ++ ; //1 
             x+=3 ; //1
        }

        }

        for(int k = 0 ; k<2*M ; K++){ //n
            if(K%7 == 4) 
                 result ++ ;
        }   

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a quick look over I would guess that the complexity is O(N^4). I qualify this as a guess because the code provided has a few typos and such, which may alter it's meaning. I have provided my interpretation below:

```
int result = 0 ;
for (int i = 0 ; i <N ; i++) { // N
  for (int j = 0 ; j <N ; j++) { //N * N

    for (int k = 0 ; k <N ; k++) { // N*N*N
      int x = 0 ; //1
      while (x < N ){ //This was x < n, but n was undefined, so assumed N. N^4
        result ++;  
        x+=3;
      }
    }

    for(int k = 0 ; k<2*N ; k++) { //N*N*(2*N), this was k<2*M, but M was undefined
        if(k%7 == 4) result++;
    }   
  }
}
```

Right, so as you can see above the for loops are three layers deep, iterating from 0 to N each time;  this can easily be seen to give us O(N^3).  However, we also have a while loop at the innermost level, which can also be characterized in terms of N - specifically `N/3` - which brings us to O(N^4).

Comment: yes that awesome answer thanks Alan but when the big o will be log n and in my question if the first line of for was like this                for (int i = 0 ; i >N ; i++) { // N} and n say = 8 i mean the condition of loop not reached so the big o will be O(1)

Comment: Sorry @YallaraceMohamed I didn't quite understand that.  Where does O(log n) come into it?

Comment: no no in this example am ask when the time complexity will be n log n

Comment: another question if the first loop was broken from the first condition then the time complexity  T(n) will be 1

Comment: There is no example in your code of a stage with the complexity `O(n.log n)`.  For an example take a look at a binary tree sort algorithm.  As for the state where `T(n) = 1` you are talking about worst and best case complexities.  These typically apply when considering properties of the input other than it's size (N); for example: a sorting algorithm being applied to an already sorted list.  Take a look at [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) for further reading.

Answer (score 0):

IF the  time complexity can be expressed as  a(n^3) + b(n^2) + c(n) + d where a,b,c and d are constants, the time complexity is O(n^3).

I guess, You are right.